# raise exclass(args) in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python-2.7, raise

When I use the 'raise' statement I meet something that I can't understand:
I know that in

> raise exclass(args)

*args*

> may be a string or a tuple containing several items of information (e.g., an error code and a string explaining the code)

but when I code this:

```
try:
    raise TypeError(float([]))
except TypeError as e:
    print e
```

I get this:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

But float([]) is neither a string nor a tuple, is it a correct way to raise an exception?

Also in this case:

```
try:
    raise float([])
except TypeError as e:
    print e
```

And I get the same result:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number
```

As I know, in the raise statement, the first argument should be a class, an instance or a string, but the code above can work successfully, why?

Please tell me how are the examples working, thanks a lot.
My English is not good, please just ignore the mistakes in grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because a list `[]` is not a valid argument for `float()`, and it has nothing to do with the exception part.

To test capturing the extra information in an exception, you can simply pass the extra data to the exception, like this:

```
>>> try:
...   raise TypeError('hello')
... except TypeError as e:
...   print(e)
... 
hello
```

You can also use the generic `Exception` class:

```
>>> try:
...    raise Exception('hello')
... except Exception as e:
...    print(e)
... 
hello
```

You can catch that particular exception like this:

```
>>> try:
...     float([])
... except TypeError:
...     print('Okay')
...
Okay
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I want is that how is 'float([])' in the example working...